# Livecode - Make client automatically reconnect on lost connection

Tags: server, client, livecode

I have a little program running on my server that controls some functions. What I want to do is create a mobile app in order to control that program in client / server mode. What I cannot do, is handle the automatic reconnection of the client on case of disconnect.

Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I'm missing lots of information. First of all, I am missing code. You need to post code that doesn't work the way you want it to work and if you do and if you tell me what it doesn't do that you want it to do, I'll tell you how to correct it. I also don't know whether you want to server or the client to reconnect automatically and I don't know whether you're having an issue with sockets that become inactive for no apparent reason (the socket seems open but the server doesn't respond anymore) or that you're dealing with an unstable network (the socket is closed and needs to be reopened). 1/2

Comment: One thing you may do checking for the openSockets using a send in time message, but this may not work if the issue you're having isn't an unstable network. 2/2

Comment: First of all, on a mobile, it is important to NOT constantly power up the network unless your app really demands it due to power constraints. And secondly, you can / should almost never trust that the connection is up and running. You should check the result of every network transaction and if it fails you might need to reconnect. But as said by @Mark it is hard to help without more info.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will actually work for you, but this is one of the ways LiveCode devs usually check for active sockets:

```
on checkSocks theSocket
  if theSocket is among the lines of the openSockets then
    send "checkSocks theSocket" to me in 5 secs
  else
    beep
    answer error "Socket" && theSock && "is unavailable."
  end if
end checkSocks
```

Call this command with the socket that you want to check as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Capture message when the socket closes

```
on socketClosed theID
  --Do your reconection stuff
end socketClosed
```

For further control you can catch socket error too

```
on socketError theID, theError
  answer error "There is a problem with the connection." \
     with "Debugging Info" or "Cancel"
  if it is "Debugging Info" then answer information theError
  close socket theID
end socketError
```

> Code snippet taken from LC Help Api